# How can one smoothly close a non closed curve?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry

Let $\alpha: [0, L] \to \mathbb{R}^2$ be smooth and such that $\langle\alpha(L) - \alpha(0), (0,1) \rangle  = 0$, $\alpha(0) \neq \alpha(L)$ and $\alpha'(0) = k\alpha'(L)$ for some $k$. We know that $x(\alpha(t))$, where $x(u,v) = (\cos(u), \sin(u), v) \ \forall (u,v) \in \mathbb{R}^2$ is closed, but $\alpha$ is not. It seems pretty intuitive to claim that $\alpha$ can always be made closed.

An example of what I mean (see sketch below) is the curve $t \mapsto (t, \sin(t))$, $t \in [0, 2\pi]$. It's very intuitive that there are infinitely many ways to "close" $\alpha$ by some other curve $\beta$ such that the curve $\omega = \alpha \cup \beta $ is also smooth and in a way that we don't lose anything, i.e, $\omega$ has all the properties $\alpha$ has. But how can we formalize this notion of the "closure" of a curve for an arbitrary smooth curve? I can't imagine any $\alpha$ that satifies the above and can't be "closed", but I'm not sure yet how to make these thoughts rigorous (the most ideal would be a constructive proof of the existence of $\beta$ for any smooth $\alpha$).
[image]

Comment: Are you asking how to prove existence of $\beta$? Or what are you asking?

Comment: I thought that was implied, but clearly it's not. I'll correct my post.

Comment: It appears from your drawing that $\alpha'(0) = -\alpha'(L)$: The tangents are oppositely oriented. Also, do you require that $\alpha + \beta$ be simple, i.e., non-self-intersecting?

Comment: I hadn't realized that, thanks. I don't want $\alpha \cup \beta$ to be necessarily simple, just smoothness will work well enough.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could connect the two endpoints with a 
[cubic Bézier curve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zier_curve#Cubic_B%C3%A9zier_curves),
which achieves 1st- and 2nd-derivative continuity
at the endpoints ($P_0$ and $P_3$ in the illustration below).

---

[image: Bezier]

      

<sup>(Image from [CartouCHe](http://www.e-cartouche.ch/content_reg/cartouche/graphics/en/html/Curves_learningObject2.htmlrl).)</sup>

---

Comment: This depends on your notion of "smooth", of course. This method will give you a curve that's $C^2$ but not in general $C^3$. I'm sure the answer is yes even for $C^\infty$ (which to me is the usual meaning of "smooth"), but it's a bit more involved -- I can go into detail if you like.

Comment: @KevinCasto: Yes, you are correct. It may be that the OP was using the word "smooth" in a non-technical sense. Second-derivative continuity is called "geometric continuity" $G^2$ in computer graphics, where that degree of smoothness usually visually suffices.

Comment: @KevinCasto the answer definitely _is_ yes for $C^\infty$ continuations, the relevant restriction mapping between (Fréchet) function spaces is a split surjection.